# How to check if a number is between an expected range?

Tags: bash, shell, numbers

I have tried two methods but it did not help:

**Method 1**

```
    port=$1
    if [[ $port -eq 3000 -o 3100 -o 3200 -o 3300 -o 3400 -o 3500 \
                         -o 3600 -o 3700 -o 3800 -o 3900]];then
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "No"
    fi
```

**Method 2**

```
    port=$1
    if [[ $port -eq 3[0-9]00 ]];then
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "No"
    fi
```

Comment: Post the code in the question, not an image.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Your method 1 is using a math check (-eq) for string values.  The [0-9] makes the r-value a string.  Your method 2 dosn't understand an OR.  It connects two tests, so you'd need [[ var -eq val1 -o var -eq val2 ]]  However, I feel that || is easier to read then -o.  Just my opinion on the latter though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct answer would be replacing `=~` with `==` because otherwise entering the number 3400000, the output would be "ok".

```
if [[ $a == 3[0-9]00 ]];then echo "ok";else echo "not ok";fi
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me, but can you please explain me the difference between =~  & ==   ?

Comment: =~ is the operator testing a regular expression match. 
In words, the test is saying "If the variable $a matches the regular expression 3[0-9]00 ..." and this match occurs if the string stored in $a CONTAINS those characters 3[0-9]00 consecutively, in order, at any point. true for the strings
3500
35000000
and many others, but not the strings
340199
3301
== the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern Matching.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Answer (score 0):

1. *POSIX*. You can switch to `case` that will recognize your initial format:

   ```
   case $a in
     3[0-9]00) echo "ok";;
     *) echo "not ok";;
   esac
   ```
2. `bash` only:

   Actually the format *3[0-9]00* is a regex format, and you can make it
   work even with if by replacing `-eq` which is used for integer
   comparison to `=~` which is used for regex matching:

   ```
   if [[ $a =~ 3[0-9]00 ]];then echo "ok";else echo "not ok";fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to a regex compare:

```
[[ $port =~ ^3[0-9]00$ ]]
```

Comment: Good idea.  I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

[*Num-utils*](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) based answer, using `numgrep`, (and `numrange`), which prints found numbers to *stdout* and returns an exit code.

First look for a number that isn't there:

```
seq 2957 19 4000 | 
  numgrep /`numrange -n, '/3000..3900i100/'`/ && a=y || a=n ; echo $a
```

Output:

```
n
```

...and now find a number that is:

```
seq 2957 7 4000 | 
  numgrep /`numrange -n, '/3000..3900i100/'`/ && a=y || a=n ; echo $a
```

Output:

```
3300
y
```

Answer (score -1):

The `(( ... ))` construct permits arithmetic expansion and evaluation. In its simplest form, `a=$(( 5 + 3 ))` would set a to `5 + 3`, or `8`. However, this double-parentheses construct is also a mechanism for allowing C-style manipulation of variables in Bash, for example, `(( var++ ))`.
Information source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=100
if (( foo >= 50 && foo <= 200 ));
then
    echo "bar"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Oybek for reply, i need to compare exactly with these 10 numbers [3000,3100,3200,3300,3400,3500,3600,3700,3800,3900]

Comment: Prem, you can divide `$port` by `100` and compare between `30`, `39` or you can put these numbers into array and check does it contain `$port`

Comment: or with an associative array to avoid the loop: `port=3200; declare -A hash=([3000]="x" [3100]="x" [3200]="x" [3300]="x" [3400]="x" [3500]="x" [3600]="x" [3700]="x" [3800]="x" [3900]="x"); if [[ -v ${hash[$port]} ]]; then echo Yes; else echo No; fi`